# Как математически в jquery уменьшить размер шрифта нажатием по кнопке

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет. Задача такая. Нужно по нажатию на кнопку что бы у каждого элемента в массиве отнималось 2px

Пример псевдокода

```
 $('.rightSide__content__gradeName li').css("top" - "2px")
```

Comment: Нужно сделать математическое вычисление

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$("#reduceFont").click(function(e) {
  $('.rightSide__content__gradeName li').each(function() {
    var oldSize = $(this).css("font-size");
    var newSize = parseInt(oldSize) - 2 + "px";
    $(this).css("font-size", newSize);
    //console.log(oldSize, newSize, $(this).css("font-size"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="reduceFont">Reduce Font</button><ul class="rightSide__content__gradeName">
  <li>One</li>
  <li style="font-size:30px;">Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Это понятно, а как сделать это математически. Т.е есть массив элементов и у каждого есть 16PX размер шрифта. Надо что бы по нажатию на кнопку было примерно так 16X - 2PX = 14PX